# GIMP 2.10 -- change GTK theme from the terminal

Tags: gtk, gimp

How can I change Gimp 2.10 theme from the terminal. Gimp is not affected by `gsettings` commands. It is also not affected by `gconftool-2` commands.

Why?

Comment: @SylvesterKruin Your coimment is for Gimp 2.99/3.00 (using GTK3) while the OP is enquiring for 2.10 which is still using GTK2.

Comment: @xenoid Quoting the [README](https://github.com/GNOME/gimp/commit/3c410273b0b65d4503e1f88e4e85ba34835d4b3a) from version 2.9 to 2.10: _The look of GIMP's interface can be customized like any other GTK app by editing the `~/.gtkrc-2.0` file or by using "themes" (ready-made
customizations).  For downloadable themes and further details, see
http://art.gnome.org/themes/gtk2 . Additionally, GIMP reads the file
`~/.config/GIMP/2.10/gtkrc` so you can have settings that only apply to GIMP._

Comment: I tested the globel configuration file `/etc/gtk-2.0/gtkrc` and it works. How come that this works while `gconftool-2` does not? Doesn't every GTK2 appliccation use schemas/databbases provided by *"GConf"*? Is it up to GUI developers that selected the GTK2 to either use (a) *"GConf"* schemas/databases and edit them with `gcconftool-2` or (b) configuration file `/etc/gtk-2.0/gtkrc`? What is it?

Comment: Is there any way to change  the look of GIMP programatically? Through terminal command?

Comment: I'm afraid that's all I can tell you at the moment; I'm not familiar with Gtk2, so aside from the Gtk2/Gtk3 overlaps, there's not much I know. I _do_ know that the [earliest release](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-tweaks/tags?after=3.0.1) in [GNOME Tweaks](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-tweaks) was in 2011. So, at some point, it was using Gtk2. Maybe you could look through the code for that release and see if there's anything helpful there.